# Remove QDomNode throws

Tags: c++, qt

I'm simply looping through a bunch of QDomNodes and based on some conditions i want to remove the QDomNode. However when i try to remove it i get this error:

> no matching function for call to 'QDomNode::removeChild(QDomNode*&)'

I'm not clear on why because the removeChild() method does in fact exist on the QDomNode class object.

```
void update_child_node(QDomNode *node) {
    if (!node->isElement()) return;

    QDomElement el = node->toElement();
    if (el.tagName() != "node") return;

    // remove old node
    QDomNode parent = node->parentNode();
    parent.removeChild(node);

}

void update_child_elements(QDomElement *root) {
    if (!root->isElement()){
        return;
    }

    QDomNodeList nodeList = root->elementsByTagName("node");
    for(int k = 0;k < nodeList.count(); k++)
    {
        QDomNode node = nodeList.at(k);
        update_child_node(&node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is misleading to to write that it throws. It does not compile is more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the `removeChild`, takes a reference: `QDomNode removeChild(const QDomNode & oldChild)`. You're passing it a pointer.

Comment: Just dereference it, or better still, don't use a pointer to begin with.